# How to perform a wait and click after finding all elements?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am having an issue trying to implement a wait and click element. What is happening with the code below is that I find all elements of an instance and then depending if I am looking for the top or bottom basket, I state which element I want to click.

The problem is that selenium is moving to fast that it is unable to find the element to click. So instead of doing

```
selectDiscountLink[0].Click();

or 

selectDiscountLink[1].Click();
```

What I really want to do is use a WaitandClickElement method. The problem is I am struggling to implement this because first of all it looks for all elements then when I choose to select a single element, I only have the option of .click(). What do I need to change in order to find all the elements and then perform a waitandclick?

public void OpenDiscountsMenu(string basketLocation)
    {
        var selectDiscountLink = _driver.FindElements(CommonPageElements.SelectDiscountsLink);

```
    if (basketLocation.ToLower() == "top")
        selectDiscountLink[0].Click();
    else
        selectDiscountLink[1].Click();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ExplicitWait` untill your all element get visible. once visible then perform your further actions

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(CommonPageElements.SelectDiscountsLink));
```

So once all your elements are there then use the same wait for individual element to be clickable like

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(selectDiscountLink[0]));
```